# Minimize and Maximize the variance of x

Tags: probability, statistics

If we have 3 p(x=i) where p1+p2+p3=1. We also know that E(X)=2. 
How do i find the values of p1,p2,p3 that maximize the var(x) and also those that minimize it?

Do we use the same method if p1+p2+p3+p4=1 and E(X)=2.5?

Thanks!

Comment: If your question means that the random variable $X$ takes on values $1, 2, 3$ with probabilities $p_1, p_2, p_3$ respectively and that $E[X]=2$, then first show that $p_1$ must equal $p_3$.  Hint: $p_1+p_2+p+3=1$ is given to you but why can you say that $p_1+2p_2+3p_3 = 2$?

Comment: Thanks Dilip, I was able to figure it out with your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those problems where intuition leads you to the correct answer.  Subject to having the correct mean, you either want the values as far apart as possible or as close together as possible.

So for a slightly more general solution to the problem where you can take the values $1,2,\ldots,n$ and the mean is $m \in [1,n]$ but not necessarily $\frac{n+1}{2}$:

- For the maximum variance let $P(X=1)=\dfrac{n-m}{n-1}$ and $P(X=n)=\dfrac{m-1}{n-1}$ and $P(X=i)=0$ for $1 \lt i \lt n$.
- For the minimum variance, if $m$ is an integer then let $P(X=m)=1$ and $P(X=i)=0$ for $i \not = m$.  Otherwise let $P(X=\lfloor m \rfloor) = \lceil m \rceil - m $ and  $P(X=\lceil m \rceil ) = m - \lfloor m \rfloor$ and $P(X=i)=0$ for $|i -m| \ge 1$.